# Pointer Assignment Clarification

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

Still learning C++ here. Trying to understand something about pointer assignments. The question I have is in the comments of the code below.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    std::string test = "foop";
    std::string * pointer;

    *pointer = test;       //Why does this crash my program...
    pointer = &test;    //But this doesn't? 

    return 0;
}
```

Based on what I've read I thought that *p = o   and   p = &o   did the same thing. I would appreciate the enlightenment.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you even try to see: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: `std::string * pointer;` You created a pointer that doesn't point at anything.

Comment: `pointer = &test;` You made your pointer point to `test`. Now the first line will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*p = o;
```

assigns `o` to the thing `p` points to. In your code `p` (or `pointer`) is uninitialized, so it assigns to god-knows-what, causing a crash (if you are lucky), or silently corrupting memory (if you aren't).

```
p = &o;
```

assigns the address of `o` to `p`, making `p` point to `o`. This is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer needs to assign the address first, in order to de-reference. 
Right now string* pointer is pointing to a garbage address! So when you assign the string foo, the program will say, I do not want "foo" to live in a dump! Then it crashes.